# ¿Es posible realizar cálculos en una propiedad enlazada(Binding) en WPF C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Tengo esta etiqueta enlazada con la propiedad Width de la ventana principal:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Width, ElementName=Ventana}" />
```

Me gustaría poder hacer esto:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Width/2, ElementName=Ventana}" />
```

Es decir, dividir el ancho entre 2 directamente en la definición del Binding. Sé que podría hacerlo desde el código e incluso utilizar un Converter, pero mi pregunta es si se podría hacer directamente sobre el código XAML. He probado de varias formas y todas me han dado error. He buscado por internet y no se comenta nada. ¿Es posible hacer algo así?
Gracias.

Comment: Buenas sin convertidor, no se puede que sepa, haciendo algún truco con estilos i bindings puede pero no compensa es mas facil con convertidor

Comment: Gracias, imaginaba algo así.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por las buenas creo que no se puede, porque lo que se "bindea" es la propiedad no el valor de ella.

Pero existe una librería llamada [CalcBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding) que hace justamente lo que necesitas.

Demo:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Name="Ventana"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:CalcBinding;assembly=CalcBinding"
        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Width, ElementName=Ventana}"  />
        <Label Content="{c:Binding Width/2, ElementName=Ventana}"  />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen el primer label muestra el width "normal" y el segundo está dividido por 2

Comment: Gracias Yussef, justo era eso lo que necesitaba. Voy a probar esa librería. Gracias por tu interesante aporte.